# What should be the table (database) structure for this situation?

Tags: sql, database-design

I have some student data, I need to save in database. Refer pic here:

[image: Student info]

I want to generate report (Pi chart, Bar graph) using these data to show that how much understanding they keep of these subject.

What would be the the table structure like to save these data, considering there would be more than 100 students in a class.

I am using SQL database.

Your suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I assume you'll be adding more students, in a similar way I also expect that you would be adding more subjects?  What about `theory, numerical`?  Are they fixed and will never change?  Or might you add additional "categories" over time?  And if you do add additional categories, will all the values for those categories always be integers?

Comment: @MatBailie yes i will be adding more no of students, but theory, numerical remain fixed.  and yes it will have integer value.

Comment: @they are fixed and will not change.

Answer (score 1):

Have one table for your students.  That will have the student name, roll number, etc, and an IDENTITY or AUTOINCREMENT column to create an INTEGER "id" column.  This is a "surrogate key" that's much more Database friendly than using external identifiers *(Such as Roll Number, which due to Sod's Law will sometimes be non-numeric, or contain a typo that needs changing after you've started recording the data)*.

Then have a similar table for Subjects.

Having the student and subject tables *(sometimes known as Dimensions)* separate from your data is called normalisation and is the basis of Relational Database Design.

Then you'd have a "Fact Table" to hold the "scores" for each student on each subject.  It should have a key pointing to the Student table, a key pointing to the Subject table and two other columns, Theory and Numerical, in which to store your data.

You can then look at UNIQUE KEY constraints, PRIMARY KEYs, FOREIGN KEY constraints, INDEXes, etc, etc.  Ideally from SQL Tutorials that are widely available on the interwebs.